# Add a postbuild event in a nuget package

Tags: dll, build, unmanaged, nuget

I am creating a nuget package and I want it to add a post-build event to my project that will copy some dll files to its target directory.

Is such a thing possible? If so, how would I do it?

Or is there a way to, somehow, embed unmanaged dll's (native C++) in my nuget package and have them copied upon build to the target directory?

Comment: I asked a little same question know but seems that nobody cares nuget here:S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I kinda figured it out by putting the unmanaged dll's in a `Dependencies` folder that I put inside the `content` directory of the nuget package.

Then my build/deploy process depends on that `Dependencies` folder. (Copy to output directory)